# Refactoring code into subdirectories

Tags: ruby, refactoring, rubygems

I have two classes called *Person* and *Animal* that have a lot of methods in them. I have a need to export some data from these classes to CSV. I also want to refactor the CSV specific code out of the class files themselves (and move it to modules). So, I created directories called *person/* and *animal/*, and put a csv_export.rb file in each (with a CSVExport Module).

```
person.rb
person/csv_export.rb
animal.rb  
animal/csv_export.rb
```

CSV exported data is different enough for the two classes that I can't just have one common csv_export.rb file (for now).

Example of person.rb:

```
class Person
  include CSVExport

  # numerous methods...
end
```

Example of csv_export.rb:

```
module CSVExport
  def to_csv
    # some logic
  end
end
```

My question is what's the correct way to namespace these two modules so they load properly? And what is the proper way to require them within *Person/Animal* (assuming the files aren't loaded by something like Rails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call the modules `Person::CSVExport` and `Animal::CSVExport`. You can `require` them (from each individual file) like this:

`require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'animal', 'csv_export.rb')`

`require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'person', 'csv_export.rb')`

This doesn't work from inside `irb` (at least in Ruby 1.9.2p290, which I am running), but it does work if a Ruby program is run from a file.

You made a good point; if you load (for example) `animal/csv_export.rb` at the top of `animal.rb`, at that point `Animal` is an undefined constant. You can get around that like this:

```
class Animal
  module CSVExport
    # contents
  end
end
```

Note that if you can, a better approach might be to build some low-level utility methods for yourself, which could make it possible to code the CSV export logic at a higher level of abstraction, and make that code short enough to go in `animal.rb` and `person.rb` without overwhelming them. I don't know what those utilities would be exactly; I'd have to see the code to offer specific suggestions.

Comment: The require tag doesn't quite work at the top of the file (before `class Person`). Since it tries to load `module Person::CSVExport` and hasn't loaded *Person* yet, *Person* is an uninitialized constant at that point. Is it appropriate to require files inside of the class block?

Comment: Hmm, doing the class -> module trick doesn't seem to work either. I'm getting "superclass mismatch for class Animal (TypeError)" on ruby 1.8.7. Seems like Animal is already defined in csv_export.rb and can't be defined again in animal.rb
Also, your require line doesn't consider that csv_export.rb is inside of animal/ directory.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Fixed one problem. To fix the other, you need to tell me what the superclass of Animal is supposed to be.